# How to change print into DataFrame in Pandas correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ib-api

I am successfully requested multiple stocks real-time data from realtimeBar from ibapi library. Like this code:

```
    def stream_data(self, reqId, time, open, high, low, close, volume, wap, count):
        print(reqId, time, open, high, low, close, volume, wap, count)
```

Output looks like this:

```
1 1647459265 158.06 158.09 158.04 158.08 175 158.06 82
0 1647459265 832.66 832.86 832.44 832.66 4 832.64 4
2 1647459265 14.89 14.9 14.89 14.9 7 14.896 5
1 1647459270 158.08 158.14 158.08 158.13 76 158.11 43
2 1647459270 14.91 14.9237 14.91 14.91 65 14.9179 46
0 1647459270 832.98 833.7 832.98 833.36 36 833.48 12
```

And it goes forever until I stopped the script.
I have a problem to insert/adapt this print in DataFrame from pandas. How should I do this? Could you show me a snippet, please? I was trying different options but different errors occurred, that's why I don't show my error type here.
I want to achieve table like this:

```
0 1647459265 832.66 832.86 832.44 832.66 4 832.64 4 1 1647459265 158.06 158.09 158.04 158.08 175 158.06 82 2 1647459265 14.89 14.9 14.89 14.9 7 14.896 5
0 1647459270 832.98 833.7 832.98 833.36 36 833.48 12 1 1647459270 158.08 158.14 158.08 158.13 76 158.11 43 2 1647459270 14.91 14.9237 14.91 14.91 65 14.9179 46
```

The goal of this DataFrame is to sort real time (every 5 sec) streaming data by reqId (because this is different stocks in fact), and make calculations (like average price, percentage change, etc.) on let's say 10 last bar (recognized by unixtime) I received.
Should I use MultiIndex? How? Or multiple DataFrames? Or maybe do you have another method, library, solution?
Any help I would highly appreciated :-)

Comment: How does your dataframe looks like? From your print statement inside your function, I imagine it has these columns: `reqId, time, open, high, low, close, volume, wap, count`. Is that it?

Comment: Exactly. I was trying several things to receive above mentioned table in df but not successful. I was trying also if and duplicate columns but also nope. Output are int and float.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, every 5 seconds you get values from `reqId, time, open, high, low, close, volume, wap, count`. Then, you want to pass them to a dataframe and sort by `reqId` and put all values with the same `time` on a single row.

I don't get why you want to combine the values with the same `time` on a single row, but I suspect you don't need to do it to achieve what you want.

I think this may help:

```py
def stream_data(self, reqId, time, open, high, low, close, volume, wap, count):
   df = pd.DataFrame(
       [[reqId, reqId, time, open, high, low, close, volume, wap, count]], colums = ['reqId', 'time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'wap', 'count'])
   df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],unit='s')
   return df
```

This will get the stream values into a dataframe and convert the unixtime to a more friendly datetime format.

Then, you can calculate whatever you want for a given frequency. For example, for your example dataframe, we can calculate the mean of every column every minute:

```py
df.groupby(['reqId', pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='30s')]).mean()

                            open    high         low    close   volume  count
reqId   time                        
0      2022-03-16 19:34:00  832.82  833.28000   832.71  833.010 20.0    8.0
1      2022-03-16 19:34:00  158.08  158.14000   158.08  158.130 76.0    43.0
2      2022-03-16 19:34:00  14.90   14.91185    14.90   14.905  36.0    25.5
1      2022-03-16 19:34:00  158.06  158.09000   158.04  158.080 175.0   82.0
```

---

After your comment, if I understood correctly, you want (or that is already happening, not sure here) to have your `stream_data` function called every 5 seconds and spit out new rows. But you are re-creating every time a dataframe with these rows that come from `stream_data`, and you want these lines added to a dataframe that has all the rows that `stream_data` has returned before.

You can just create an empty dataframe and then keep appending new rows to it. Then, you filter the rows you want do do your calculations as I suggested above.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame
def stream_data(self, reqId, time, open, high, low, close, volume, wap, count):
   new_rows = pd.DataFrame(
       [[reqId, reqId, time, open, high, low, close, volume, wap, count]], colums = ['reqId', 'time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'wap', 'count'])
   new_rows['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],unit='s')
   return new_rows

df = pd.concat([df, new_rows])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I still need something more/different. I know it's hard to understand me if even me not sure how to define what I want :) so I appreciate any help :) I need to add it like streaming, every 5 seconds should appear new n rows, where n is distinct reqId (in this situation is 3 rows per 5 sec). Case is, now I still can't calculate previous rows, for example find the percentage diff between numbers in exact rows from 19:33:00 and 19:33:05, because now in memory is only 19:33:15row (and its updating/overwriting, not adding +1(+3/+n) rows to dataframe). Same xlsx/csv

Comment: I edited the answer. I hope the last part of it helps you.